# How to import external font in Angular 4 project?

Tags: angular, less

I have `styles.less` in the root of my ng project where I am importing a google font:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700&subset=cyrillic');
```

But the error occurs:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./src/styles.less
Module build failed: 

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700&subset=cyrillic');

^
Can't resolve './https://fonts.googleapis.com/cssfamily=PT+Sans:400,700&subset=cyrillic' in 'C:\apps-dev\ldrm\src' in C:\apps-dev\ldrm\src\styles.less (line 1, column 0)

@./src/styles.less 4:14-187

@multi ./src/styles.less
```

Comment: Please check this repo - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3176

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular is adding "./" on this call. See [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#base-href) the reason for it.

You have 2 options:

1. include the font in your index.html
2. download the font, place it in the assets folder and call it like this:

   ```
   @font-face {
       font-family: 'your-font-family';
       src: url('/assets/fonts/your-donwloaded-font-1'), 
            url('/assets/fonts/your-donwloaded-font-2');
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
@chosen-font: 'PT Sans';
@chose-font-escaped: escape(@chosen-font);
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=@{chose-font-escaped}:400,700&subset=cyrillic');
```